# FastAPI: How to test APIs by overriding functions in `Depends()`

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, fastapi

I am very, very new to FastAPI testing, so any guidance in the right direction would be appreciated.

So what I have right now is as follows:

A very simple routes file: datapoint_routes.py

```
from fastapi import APIRouter, Depends

datapoint_router = APIRouter()


def some_function_is():
    return "Actual"


@datapoint_router.get('/{datapoint_name}')
def get_db(
    datapoint_name: str,
    some_function_output=Depends(some_function_is)
) -> dict:
    return {
        'datapoint_name': datapoint_name,
        'state': some_function_output
    }
```

I want to be able to test this. I checked out [FastAPI Testing Dependencies guide here](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/testing-dependencies/). But this did not help at all, because it didn't work for me.

---

For my tests, what I have right now is something like this:

File: test_datapoint_router.py

```
from typing import Union

from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient

from datapoint_routes import datapoint_router, some_function_is


DATAPOINT_NAME = 'abcdef'

app = FastAPI()
client = TestClient(datapoint_router)


def override_dep(q: Union[str, None] = None):
    return "Test"


app.dependency_overrides[some_function_is] = override_dep


def test_read_main():
    response = client.get(f"/{DATAPOINT_NAME}")
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert response.json() == {
        'datapoint_name': DATAPOINT_NAME,
        'state': "Test"
    }
```

I would hope in the test, the `response = client.get()` would be based on the overriding function `override_dep`, which would replace `some_function_is`.

I thought the `response.json()` would be:

```
{
    'datapoint_name': 'abcdef',
    'state': 'Test'
}
```

instead, it is:

```
{
    'datapoint_name': 'abcdef',
    'state': 'Actual'
}
```

This means that the `override_dep` function in the test is useless.

I even checked out the value of `app.dependency_overrides`, and it shows a correct map:

```
(Pdb) app.dependency_overrides
{<function some_function_is at 0x102b3d1b0>: <function override_dep at 0x102b3e0e0>}
```

Where the memory values of functions do match:

```
(Pdb) some_function_is
<function some_function_is at 0x102b3d1b0>

(Pdb) override_dep
<function override_dep at 0x102b3e0e0>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have an complete, reproducible example that shows the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating the FastAPI `app` object *in your test*, but you're using a defined *router* with your `TestClient`. Since this router is never registered with the app, overriding a dependency with the app won't do anything useful.

The TestClient is usually used with the root app (so that the tests run against the app itself):

```py
from fastapi import APIRouter, Depends, FastAPI

app = FastAPI()
datapoint_router = APIRouter()

def some_function_is():
    return "Actual"


@datapoint_router.get('/{datapoint_name}')
def get_db(
    datapoint_name: str,
    some_function_output=Depends(some_function_is)
) -> dict:
    return {
        'datapoint_name': datapoint_name,
        'state': some_function_output
    }

app.include_router(datapoint_router)
```

And then the test:

```py
from typing import Union

from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
from datapoint_routes import app, datapoint_router, some_function_is


DATAPOINT_NAME = 'abcdef'

client = TestClient(app)


def override_dep(q: Union[str, None] = None):
    return "Test"


app.dependency_overrides[some_function_is] = override_dep


def test_read_main():
    response = client.get(f"/{DATAPOINT_NAME}")
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert response.json() == {
        'datapoint_name': DATAPOINT_NAME,
        'state': "Test"
    }
```

This passes as expected, since you're now testing against the app (`TestClient(app)`) - the location where you overrode the dependency.

Answer (score 1):

[MatsLindh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72387919/3800552) does solve the problem, and I would like to suggest another improvement.

Overriding the depends function at the root of the test file, introduces a risk of interfering with the following tests, due to a lack of cleanup.

Instead, I suggest using a fixture, which would ensure the isolation of your tests. I wrote a simple pytest plugin to integrate with the dependency system of FastAPI to simplify the syntax as well.

Install it via: `pip install pytest-fastapi-deps` and then use it like so:

```
from typing import Union

from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
from datapoint_routes import app, datapoint_router, some_function_is

DATAPOINT_NAME = 'abcdef'

client = TestClient(app)


def override_dep(q: Union[str, None] = None):
    return "Test"


def test_read_main_context_manager(fastapi_dep):
    with fastapi_dep(app).override({some_function_is: override_dep}):
        response = client.get(f"/{DATAPOINT_NAME}")
        assert response.status_code == 200
        assert response.json() == {
            'datapoint_name': DATAPOINT_NAME,
            'state': "Test"
        }
```